# how to make ansible get access to an sshd container?

Tags: docker, ansible, openssh

I use an ansible script to load & start the https://hub.docker.com/r/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd/ container.

so it starts well of course :

```
bash-4.4$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
8bedbd3b7d88        rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd   "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"   37 minutes ago      Up 36 minutes       0.0.0.0:49154->22/tcp   test
bash-4.4$
```

so after ansible failure on ssh access to it I tested manually from shell
this is also ok.

```
bash-4.4$ ssh root@172.17.0.2
The authenticity of host '172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:YtTfuoRRR5qStSVA5UuznGamA/dvf+djbIT6Y48IYD0.
ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:43:3f:41:e9:89:45:06:6f:f6:42:c4:6a:70:37:f8:1d.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '172.17.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@172.17.0.2's password: 
root@8bedbd3b7d88:~# logout
Connection to 172.17.0.2 closed.
bash-4.4$
```

so the step that failed is trying to get on it from ansible script & make access to ssh-copy-id

ansible error message is :

```
Fatal: [172.17.0.2]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '172.17.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}


---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: start docker service 
    service: 
      name: docker
      state: started
  - name: load and start the container we wanna use 
    docker_container:
      name: test
      image: rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd
      state: started
      ports:
       - "49154:22"
  - name: Wait maximum of 300 seconds for ports to be available 
    wait_for:
      host: 0.0.0.0
      port: 49154
      state: started

- hosts: 172.17.0.2
  vars:
    passwordadmin: $6$pbE6yznA$AeFIdI.....K0
    passwordroot: $6$TMrxQUxT$I8.JIzR.....TV1
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
  tasks:
  - name: Build test container root user rsa ssh-key
    shell: docker exec test ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""
```

so I cannot even run the needed step to build ssh 
how to do then ??

1. 1st step (ansible task) : load docker container
2. 2cd step (ansible task on only 172.17.0.2) : connect to it & setup it
3. there will be 3rd step to run application on it after that.

the problem occurs only when starting the 2cd step

Comment: It seems the problem is not with the connection but with the authentication (It says "Permission denied"). Have you supplied the ssh password in your inventory or when invoking ansible?

Comment: of course not there is not yet password - I have to build key / startup ssh / generate a password on the remote container at first --- before I can update any ansible localhost ssh setup information

Comment: Well according to the documentation of the docker image the password is `root`. But I didn't look at the command you're trying to run - the `docker` command you actually want to run on the host-system so the `host` would have to be `127.0.0.1` for the second task

Comment: no I have to run on docker image  not  localhost after the 1st task is done

Comment: Yes and `docker exec test` takes care of that you basically say "run the following command in the container named `test`". But you have to run this in the context of the host (since that is the place where the container is running).

Comment: ok for that. but 1st  I have to solve the connection issue between ansible and it .

Answer (score -1):

Ok after many trys on a second container 
conclusion  is my procedure was bad

what I have done to solve that :

1. build a diroctory tree separating ./ ./inventory ./includes
2. build 1 yaml file by host (local, docker, labo)
3. build 1 main yaml file on ./
4. build 1 new host file in ./inventory
5. connect forced by sshpass  to docker on default password
6. changed it
7. add the host key on authorized key to a login dedicated usage
8. installed pyhton (**needed to answer ansible host** *else it makes
   randomly module errors or refused connections depending on current
   action*)
9. setup a ssh login user in sudoers
10. then I can un the docker.yaml actions
11. then only at last I can run the labo.yaml actions.

Thanks for help

now I'm able to build the missing tools.